# EF 4.1 RC Many to many relationship in EF CF

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, many-to-many, entity-framework-4.1, fluent-interface

I have two entities with many to many relationship like this:

```
class author
{
  public int AuthorID{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<book> books{get;set;}
}
class book
{
  public int BookID{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
 public virtual ICollection<author> authors{get;set;}

}
```

and I have an intermediate table named Bookauthor defined like this:

```
  BookAuthor: int
  int AuthorID
  int BookID
```

How to map this using FluentAPI

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was problematic with EDMX but with EF 4.1 fluent API **you can map it**:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<book>()
            .HasMany(b => b.authors)
            .WithMany(a => a.books)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("BookID")
                   .MapRightKey("AuthorID")
                   .ToTable("BookAuthor"));
```

As you can see I don't map `BookAuthor` column. That column is unknown to EF and must be auto incremented.

This obviously can't work with a Code-first approach but only if you use Fluent API against existing database.

Comment: it is working? really? with which condition? 4.1 doesnt care about OnModelCreating override. I am really living shock. ToTable("BookAuthor")  doesn't create a table which is call by BookAuthor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think EF allows you to have a separate Id in many-to-many junction tables.

The alternative is just mapping BookAuthor as an entity.

On a side note, NHibernate supports this construct using an [idbag](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-idbag)